# redirect user from index page if session is still not destroyed

Tags: php

How to redirect user if he opens a new tab then type the index.php of my page to his user page? What will I put in my index.php to do this? I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: user_page.php');
}
```

Make sure that you don't have any html code or spacing above this in your index.php

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question has been answered a lot on stackoverflow.

```
header("Location:filename")
exit();
```